# How to use an object to delete it from objects array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects and I want to check whether a given object is present in the array and if yes,I want to delete that,If not I have to add it to the array.

I am doing this:

```
 var arr=[
       {
        name: "Jack",
        type: "Jill",
        },
        {
        name: "Heer",
        type: "Ranjha",
        },
       {
        name: "laila",
        type: "Majnu",
        };

]
 
var tosearch = {
        name: "Jack",
        type: "Jill",
        };
if(arr.includes(tosearch))
{
//I want to delete it from the arr.
}
else
   arr.push(tosearch)
```

How can I achieve the above implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`Array.prototype.includes` only works for primitives and object via shallow reference equality, i.e. if they are the same object in memory.

## Solution

Create a utility to check if the array contains *some* element where *every* property of the "search" object is equal.

```
const arrayContainsObject = (array, object) =>
  array.findIndex((el) =>
    Object.entries(object).every(([key, value]) => el[key] === value)
  );
```

This example returns the index of the element if found, otherwise it returns `-1`.

You can use this to either filter the element from the array or append it.

```
let result;
const index = arrayContainsObject(arr, toSearch);

if (index !== -1) {
  result = arr.filter((el, i) => i !== index);
} else {
  result = arr.concat(toSearch);
}
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Jack",
    type: "Jill"
  },
  {
    name: "Heer",
    type: "Ranjha"
  },
  {
    name: "laila",
    type: "Majnu"
  }
];

const toSearch = {
  name: "Jack",
  type: "Jill"
};

const arrayContainsObject = (array, object) =>
  array.findIndex((el) =>
    Object.entries(object).every(([key, value]) => el[key] === value)
  );

let result;
const index = arrayContainsObject(arr, toSearch);

if (index !== -1) {
  result = arr.filter((el, i) => i !== index);
} else {
  result = arr.concat(toSearch);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This seems a long way to filter, why not just using the first arg of your filter function to do that?

Comment: Its working,just want to know how fast and efficient it is

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I don't follow your comment, filtering by index is pretty standard in React.

Comment: @rudeTool `O(n^2)` to find the index (`O(n)` outer loop over array, `O(n)` inner loop on element properties), `O(n)` to filter, `O(n)` on the concat to return a new array.

Comment: @rudeTool Sorry, misspoke a bit, it'd be a bit more accurate to say `O(n*m)` where `n` is the number of elements of the outer array iterated on and `m` the number of properties to search by, but `O(n^2)` is loosely the general upper bound.

Comment: I am saying that you are already using filter so why do you need such complexity with findIndex and every, same result can be achieve just with filter.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Is it not obvious? You need to first check if the array contains a matching element (*i.e. all properties equal*) ***before*** either filtering it from the array, or adding it to the array. It was part of the OP's requirements. Finding the index first and queuing from it makes the filter operation a trivial matter. In other words, once you determine an element needs to be removed you don't need to find the match again via the element properties when you can just check the index. OFC, if you check only one property for matching then you can just filter it as in your solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code

```
arr = arr.filter(item => item !== tosearch)
```

but, there is better way for handle this you can add an id field for each object and wherever you want to check and find specific item you can use that id

```
arr = arr.filter(item => item.id !== tosearch.id)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I have detailed the step below to create utilities based on this core principle

Answer (score 3):

Deleting an element from an array using filter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const newArray = existingArray.filter(element => element.id != deleteId);
```

Searching I usually use a simple findIndex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```
const doesElementExist = arr.findIndex(element => element.id === selectedId);

if (doesElementExist > 0) { // Delete element }
```

This relies on you having a unique identifier in the object potentially the name? I am not sure what your data will be.

Comment: Also exist, and +1 for the `findIndex` that might solve the unexplained used case of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve filtering:

```js
/** utils.js */


// default options can be set, here we will create search filter which pick from id
const defaultSearchFilterOptions = { key: 'id', pick: true }


/**
 * @description
 * factory to create array filter utilities
 * @params {object} [options={}] - options used to generate the new filter
 * @params {string} [options.key='id'] - key used for comparing
 * @params {boolean} [options.pick=true] - inverse the filter (with/without)
 * @params {string} options.search - exact match to search (can be improved with a regex or whatever etc..
 * @returns {function} filter - function that can be used with `Array.prototype.filter`
 */
function createSearchFilter(options = {}) {
  // apply user's options on top of default options, user MUST pass at least "search" options
  const { key, search, pick } = { ...defaultSearchFilterOptions, ...options }
  // return a filter function, based on computed options
  return (item) => pick ? item[key] === search : item[key] !== search
}


/** app.js */

// data
var arr = [
  {
    name: "Jack",
    type: "Jill",
  },
  {
    name: "Heer",
    type: "Ranjha",
  },
  {
    name: "laila",
    type: "Majnu",
  }
];


// using factory, create a filter on name where value is "jack"
const filterInJack = createSearchFilter({ 
  key: 'name',
  search: 'Jack',
});

// using factory, create a filter on name where value is not "jack"
const filterOutJack = createSearchFilter({ 
  key: 'name',
  search: 'Jack',
  pick: false,
});

/** Results */

console.log(arr.filter(filterInJack));

console.log(arr.filter(filterOutJack));
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

If the number of properties are fixed(in your case its 2 `name` and `type`) and you know them before running then you can simply use this.

This approach may not be an ideal one but if the data is of this type then i guess this might be might be a good and easy to understand approach

```
//here i is the index of a object in arr
if(arr[i].name == tosearch.name && arr[i].type == tosearch.type) {
   //delete it
} else {
   arr.push(tosearch);
}
```